# .NET Core - Push a HttpRequest into the middleware pipline

Tags: .net-core, httprequest, webapi

A customer of us came up with quite a strange security rule and I am not sure whether it is even possible to do without losing most of the .NET Core Web API features.

Within their ruleset, the server within the dmz is not allowed to create a connection to an intranet service / server. Also the extranet server is not allowed to expose any user or customer data directly to a server within the internet.

Normally I would simply use some kind of reverse proxy and forward these requests to the service within the intranet, but because of restricted connection setup this is not allowed...

[image]

So, I thought about some kind of bridge, where the internal server connects to the external server via (Web-)Socket connection and then the external server pushes the complete request over that connection to the internal server. Afterwards some kind of ASP.NET Core middleware pushes this request data into the common request flow. But the middleware pipeline delegate is normally kicked in by a HTTP request, which never happens.

Is there a way to handle this scenario in a convenient or common way and at best without losing features like websockets and so on?

Comment: it looks like the external server would run some kind of open source api-gateway software

Comment: As Far as i know, an api-gateway still calls the internal server by itself, so the connection is opened by the external server, which is not allowed in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few solutions, but both are complete conjecture, though.

You could push the request info through the web socket to the internal handler that then calls the internal web endpoint using an `HttpClient`. Effectively, the internal server is calling itself over an HTTP connection from localhost, which would engage the whole pipeline. Then it would push the result back to the external server.

A different (less likely to work) way would be for you to somehow copy all the pipeline middleware to the external server and then, over the web socket call the handler. The handler would then construct an instance of the controller and call the method directly, bypassing the internal middleware (because the middleware would have executed elsewhere).

I suspect the latter approach will likely be a no-go because the copied middleware does things that can't be done on the external server in the first place.

The right way to do it in my opinion, though, would be to do the reverse proxy, but define a *very restrictive* allow list on the proxy and in the internal server. That would take convincing your client of course!

Comment: Actually your first approach, was also my first intension, which i also start to implement. But in this constellation, i will probably lose the initial connection information, which may lead security related issues, because having a valid usertoken can't be checked against the calling connection. Maybe it would be an option to add some kind of Bridge-Mode on the internal server, with an additional middleware and additional Bridge-Headers, where to add the initial client connection info. But in my opinion that sounds a little bit wired.